# How to back to previous view controller with parameters in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.3.1

TableViewController B shows up when a button in ViewController A is tapped. A user selects an item in B and then is led back to A. I used the following code to go back to A from B. But how can I pass the selected item `([Int: String])` to A?

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Below is the code to navigate to B from A

```
 let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

 let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("categories") as! CategoryListViewController

 self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ViewController A` class  create an empty  `Dictionary` like this

```
var dict = [Int: String]()
```

Now when you move from `TableViewController B` to `ViewController A` set the value  to `dict` like this

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

 let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("categories") as! CategoryListViewController

// here you pass parameter to ViewController A

nextViewController.dict =  YourVaribleWhichStrore[Int:String] 

 self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: In case if you need any help tell me?